# JavaMail - Header order

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm facing some problems because my mail header is out of order. Is possible to keep order that i've added itens? I would like that all my custom header information are before header "Return-Path".

I have read about the method addHeader(key, value) and something like a reverse but i don't know how to to it.

Here is how it's being generated:

```
Return-Path: 00093b6a.000127712516@urx.com
From: =?UTF-8?B?RGVzZW52b2x2aW1lbnRvIFRlc3Rlcw==?= <bla@bla.net>
Reply-To: Test Dev <bla@bla.net>
To: bla.bla@bla.net
Message-ID: <342723268.1.1430361334441.JavaMail.bla.bla@uhew>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VGVzdGUgQ29uZWN0IENhcg==?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_1634925367.1430361334427"
X-Receiver: bla.bla@bla.net
X-RPTags: 
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:None?subject=unsubscribe:00093b6a.000127712516>
X-Envid: 00605034.000127712516
X-MsgID: 00093b6a.000127712516
x-virtual-mta: NGMistoURX
X-rpcampaign: NGZDesenv605034
X-Sender: 00093b6a.000127712516@urx.com
X-UmailPersonalization: 2388627
X-Mailer: Generator V3
```

And is here how i would like that my information was generated:

```
X-Receiver: bla.bla@bla.net
X-RPTags: 
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:None?subject=unsubscribe:00093b6a.000127712516>
X-Envid: 00605034.000127712516
X-MsgID: 00093b6a.000127712516
x-virtual-mta: NGMistoURX
X-rpcampaign: NGZDesenv605034
X-Sender: 00093b6a.000127712516@urx.com
X-UmailPersonalization: 2388627
X-Mailer: Generator V3
Return-Path: 00093b6a.000127712516@urx.com
From: =?UTF-8?B?RGVzZW52b2x2aW1lbnRvIFRlc3Rlcw==?= <bla@bla.net>
Reply-To: Test Dev <bla@bla.net>
To: bla.bla@bla.net
Message-ID: <342723268.1.1430361334441.JavaMail.bla.bla@uhew>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VGVzdGUgQ29uZWN0IENhcg==?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_1634925367.1430361334427"
```

This is how i add a header information

```
headerData.foreach(header => message.addHeader(header._1, header._2) )
```

Any idead?

Thank in advance

Comment: Header order should not matter; [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) says it doesn't. Which means you shouldn't need to care. So, why do you care?

Comment: I care because we are using PowerMTA and i need to receive the value of "envelope-from" the same value of "X-Sender" and it only works if my tags are before "Return-Path".

Comment: Oh dear... If this is so PowerMTA is really broken. But this "precision" should be in your question, really.

Comment: If i could change it on application level, is better and simple. Is it possible?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea at all... I have never had to do that

Comment: Related: [Headers order for InternetHeaders read from stream are not always correct](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6275)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, header order **really** isn't supposed to matter.

If you need to put all your headers in a particular order at the beginning of the message, the simplest approach is to subclass MimeMessage and override the writeTo method to write out your headers before calling super.writeTo.  You'll probably want to keep your headers in a separate List or InternetHeaders object.